# the jar of this class file belongs to container android private libraries

Tags: android, parse-platform

I tried so many solutions, and its either non understandable for a beginner level or it doesn't work

[Here's](http://s28.postimg.org/8giaajeel/error.png) the problem shown in the picture

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jar files are kind of compressed Java code files. You can execute them, but are unable to make any change in them. 
It seems you clicked some Eclipse function like 'go to definition' or 'edit class', but you can't actually see/edit contents of a jar file.

It is not a problem - it is purposely done like this.

Comment: It crash my application, so its a problem for me at least

Comment: Ok, so can you please explain the whole case: what you are trying to achieve, what is actually doing and what is the stacktrace.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562608/android-runtime-and-nullpoint-exceptions) question it has all the details, thank you in advance :)